# How do I fix my discord bot only responding in DM's?

Tags: discord.py

My discord bot is only responding in DMs. Even when using commands in a server, the bot still only responds in DMs.

This is the code:
https://replit.com/@okapikit/goosidk

I searched online for similar problems and they said to enable intents, but it still doesn't work after all intents are enabled. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is only answering in DMs as you are using `author.send` which is sending the message directly to the author in their DMs. You can fix this by using `channel.send` which would look something like this in your case:

```
if is_private:
  await message.author.send(response)
else:
  await message.channel.send(response)
```

Here I have assumed that you want to send a message privately in their DMs if `is_private` is true, if this isn't the case then I'm sure you can figure out how to alter it to suit your needs from this.